# How to stop SQLAlchemy session transaction in a query?

Tags: mysql, sqlalchemy

The [SQLAlchemy's docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_transaction.html) say: "When you use a session to query, the session get transaction started". In fact, every operation is a transaction.

But it has a question, I'm using a MySQL middleware--mycat for Read/Write Splitting, if you send a transaction, all queries are transferred to the write server, even if it is a select query.

I wish to let the query not enable transactions without using the raw SQL query. So how to stop SQLAlchemy session transaction? Or change MySQL middleware to better?

Comment: No, it is not "every operation is a transaction", it is that **every operation is *in* a transaction**

Comment: @AnttiHaapala All right,so,we can't let a operation not in a transaction?i wish have some parameter  can control  let a query work like raw sql